# The Reputation Leagues doesn't show all users, and has incorrect stats for some people

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

https://stackexchange.com/leagues/4/month/meta-stackoverflow/2010-10-01?sort=totalreputation

Two problems:

- Most of the top Meta users aren't even listed (myself included; I don't show up by searching either)
- Stats for some people are incorrect (for example, @random is listed with ~18.9k, yet he actually has almost 22k).

**EDIT:** This may be localized to Meta stats because of the server migration. If that's the case, it seems odd that *any* information would show up.

The screenshot shows the page sorted by total reputation:

[image]

Comment: Yes, it looks like something went horribly wrong tonight just with meta.so because of the migration...we'll figure it out tomorrow morning

Comment: That 18K is correct and has been since just before MetaSU opened up. Have not gotten around to a self-done rep recalc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now.  Looks like we ran afoul of our own rate limiter last night when hitting meta.SO's api.